# Zorn Lemma: (Halmos' book) what are the advantages of working with collections of chains?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is a follow up to [Explanation of Proof of Zorn's lemma in Halmos's Book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163905/explanation-of-proof-of-zorns-lemma-in-halmoss-book)

**Zorn's lemma.** If X is a partially ordered set such that every chain in X has an upper bound, then X contains a maximal element.

**Proof sketch.**

**step 1:**

Let  be collection of weak initial segments of elements of X, ordered by set inclusion; we show that if  has a maximal set, then X has a maximal element

**step 2:**

Let  be the collection of all chains in X, ordered by set inclusion; show that if  has a maximal set, then  has a maximal set

The passage from  to  cannot introduce any new maximal elements.

**Question**

My question concerns the following comment by Halmos in Naive Set Theory:

One advantage of the collection  is the slightly more specific form that the chain hypothesis assumes; instead of saying that each chain  has some upper bound in , we can say explicitly that the union of the sets of , which is clearly an upper bound of , is an element of the collection .

I presume that Halmos is referring to an advantage of   over .

But this advantage is not clear to me.

Wouldn't the exact same property, claimed to be an advantage of  , apply to  ?

Assume that we define  as a chain in .

Why can't we say explicitly that the union of the sets of , (which also is clearly an upper bound of ?), is an element of the collection ?

In summary: I don't understand the first advantage of    over , claimed by Halmos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the union of a chain is an upper bound of that chain does **not** hold for $\mathcal{S}$. Recall that a weakly initial segment is a set of the form $\{a: a\le b\}$ for some fixed $b$; that is, every weakly initial segment has (in fact, is determined by) a top element. To quote Halmos:

> More precisely, we consider, for each element $x\in\mathcal{X}$, the weak initial segment $\overline{s}(x)$ consisting of $x$ and all its predecessors.

This means that if I have a chain in $\mathcal{S}$ with no greatest element, the union of this chain will *not* be an element of $\mathcal{S}$!

For example, take my poset to be $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ with the usual ordering, and let $[n]=\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$. Then $\{[n]: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a chain in $\mathcal{S}$, but its union is $\mathbb{N}$, which is not an element of $\mathcal{S}$.

---

Halmos also lists a second advantage: that a subset of an element of $\mathcal{X}$ is an element of $\mathcal{X}$. Note that this again fails for $\mathcal{S}$: e.g. in the example above, the set $\{1, 12\}$ is a chain - so an element of $\mathcal{X}$ - but is not a weak initial segment - that is, not an element of $\mathcal{S}$. But $\{1, 12\}$ is a subset of $\{1, 2, 3, . . . , 12\}=[12]$, which *is* an element of $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.  Now I understand that a chain of weakly initial segments may be infinite, therefore the union of the elements of the chain may not be a weakly initial segment.    In contrast, if we consider a chain of subsets of a set, irrespectively of being finite or infinite, we will always have that its union is an element of the chain.  I guess I was too focused on chains that have an upper bound (as referred to in the statement of Zorn's lemma), and did not note that at this point in the proof the author was referring to arbitrary chains.

Comment: In your reply, you mentioned that: 

This means that if I have a chain in S with no greatest element, the union of this chain will not be an element of S!

However, from the statement of Zorn lemma, the observation above does not apply, right?  (every chain has a greatest element)

Comment: @DanielS. It is **not** the case that every chain has a greatest element. Every chain has an upper bound, but there are lots of chains in any interesting (set-theoretically speaking) poset which do not have maximal elements.

Comment: Every upper bound is a maximal element, right?   So, if every chain has an upper bound, every chain has a maximal element?   Based on your comments: 

1) Every chain A in X has an upper bound in X (not necessarily in A),

2) Every chain C in stylized-S has an upper bound in stylized-S, but not necessarily all the upper bounds of a chain C are in stylized-S 

3) Every chain C in stylized-X has an upper bound in stylized-X, and all the special sorts of upper bounds of chains which can be obtained by the union of elements in C are in stylized-X